# How can I access the changed data in using office.js

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-app

I'm developing a software on `Excel` as an **App for Office**, using `office.js`.

For some part, I'm hooking to a table in the excel to check if its data is changed using following code:

```
myBinding.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged, onBindingDataChanged);


function onBindingDataChanged(eventArgs) {
    // eventArgs has just the binding info.
    // I want to have selected cell row and column, and old and new data.
}
```

Unfortunately the information in `eventArgs` is not enough for me to detect changes.
Worth to mention that for Office.EventType.Binding**Selection**Changed, there's lots of usable information such as `startRow, startColumn, ...`.

So my question is: 
How can I access these information:

- Changed Row
- Changed Column
- Old Data
- New Data

Answer (score 1):

I created a excel app too. You could get the current data and compare them with the old data. Then save the new data as the old data.

```
var oldData = null;

function onBindingDataChanged(eventArgs) {
    var id = eventArgs.binding.id;
    Office.select('bindings#'+id).getDataAsync(handleNewData);
}

function handleNewData(asyncResult) {
    var newData = asyncResult.value;

    if (oldData != null) {
        // detect changes here
    }

    oldData = newData;
);
```

Comment: I'm binding to a whole table, so keeping the whole table in `oldData` would be so expensive. I want to have just the changed data, not the whole table and detecting changes via comparing the whole table.

Comment: of what table size we are talking about? maybe you can hold it in the localstorage? When you want to access the old data, you have to save it somewhere...